# git diff origin/master, how to query diff from the server?

Tags: git

I just set up a git repository. I am trying to learn how to use the tool.

On computer A I do:

```
git add foo.c
  git commit -a -m "version 1.0"
  git push --mirror user@server:/home/git/pilot
```

On computer B I do:

```
git clone user@MainServer:/home/git/pilot
```

Now I get my change 1.0 on computer B

Question:
The first problem I see is that it says /c/temp/pilot (master), shouldn't it say something else? The master is the MainServer.

On computer A I make another change, commit and push it to the server

On computer B if I do:

```
git diff origin/master
```

I don't see any difference, but if I do:

```
git pull
```

I get the latest
What am I doing wrong?
How can I set up my Computer B database to be dependent on the MainServer?

Thanks Tony

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong. This is git, not svn. There is no "server".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git diff` does not fetch the latest changes from the origin remote. You have to run `git fetch origin` prior to `git diff`.

On the other hand, `git pull` already includes the fetching step (and also merges the remote changes).